# Использования видеокарты для компиляции проекта на python3.10

Tags: python, python-3.x

Добрый день что если я хочу чтобы моя видеокарта обрабатывала проект на python3.10 а не на процессоре так как я считаю что видеокарта куда быстрее справиться с этим вот проект:

```
import numpy as np

my_file = open("byletipe.txt", "w")
a = (''.join([np.random.choice(list('QWERTYUIOP[]ASDFGHJKL;ZXCBNM,./')) for x in range(1000000000)]))
my_file.write(str(a))
my_file.close()
```

на создание кучи символов в txt файле уходит около 2-3часов но я думаю если использовать мощность видеокарты то всё будет куда бодрее как это реализовать и как реализовать в будешь

Comment: Ну вообще эффективнее не в всю строку сразу формировать, а формировать блоками, и поблочно сохранять их файл. Видеокарта не поможет, тут скорее всего в скорость внешнего носителя больше будет упираться, а не в процессор.

Comment: я думаю что просто чтобы он быстре работал

Comment: Не мог бы ты скинуть переработанный код для наглядности пожалуйста

Comment: Вообще даже вот такая простая замена `a = ''.join(random.choice('QWERTYUIOP[]ASDFGHJKL;ZXCBNM,./') for x in range(1000000000))` будет значительно быстрее работать (проверял на 1000000 - давало 0.29 секунды вместо 6.16 секунд, т.е. примерно в 20 раз разница).

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что вопрос относится к "Проблема XY"